# Versioncode of android application changing when i upload to play store cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have uploaded apk with versioncode 1.

```
 <widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
      version="1.0"
      android-versionCode="1"
      ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3">
```

When i upload to play store it is showign versioncode as "18"

Can anybody faced issue with version code